# How to fix unexpected return when JSLint-ing a requireJS application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, requirejs, jslint

My application is running `requireJS` and is set up using two files:

`main.js` sets everything and `app.js` "runs" the application.

`main.js` looks like this:

```
/*jslint browser: true, indent : 2, nomen : true, sloppy : true */
/*global requirejs: false */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: "../js"
      , paths: {
          app:          'app'
        , text:         'text'
        ...
      }
      , shim: {
        'overrides':     { deps: ['jquery'] }
        ...
      }
  });

  // init
  requirejs([ 'overrides',..., 'app'], 
    function( $, overrides, ..., App){
      App.start( $, overrides );
    });
}());
```

And my `app.js`:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';
    var start = function () {
        require([ 'i18next'... ],
            function (i18n) {
                // stuff

            }
        );
    }
    return {"start": start};
});
```

My problem is that `jslint` complains about the `return {"start": start};` as `unexpected return`. However, omitting it will cause my application to not start because of `App being undefined`.

Any idea how to remove the return-statement and still trigger the application? Or how to tweak to please JSLint? I don't want to use JSHINT, so please don't suggest it.

Comment: nothing wrong, but I'm almost passing JSLint, so... why settle for JSHint.

Comment: Depends on how serious you are about "passing the test". I see linting as HTML&CSS validation, if there's a reason to break the rule then I don't want it to bother me, that's why I prefer JSHint, you have more options to tweak to your needs.

Comment: true. but I kind of got stuck on JSLint. Still thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @frequent: *"...but I'm almost passing JSLint, so... why settle for JSHint..."* Remember there's nothing delivered on a stone tablet about jslint. About half of it is Crockford's *style* preferences, with no basis other than that. (The other half is good sound stuff with a factual basis.) The nice thing about JSHint is it lets you decide whether you want to use Crockford's style or your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start by adding the missing semicolon:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';
    var start = function () {
        require([ 'i18next'... ],
            function (i18n) {
                // stuff

            }
        );
    }   // <============ here
    return {"start": start};
});
```

I suspect that's the real reason jslint is unhappy. (I'm surprised that's not what it's complaining about...)

Comment: MAGIC! That did it. Can't be that `jslint` is not looking for semi-colons when a function is setup as a `var x = function(){}!!;!!` now, can it?

Comment: @frequent: I'm really surprised that it gets the error message wrong, but I'm glad that fixed it!